# Fastest way to assign values to class property in typescript class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, interface

Here is my class and an interface:
As you can see I have to write lines for all properties. Can we reduce the lines here?

```
interface requestQAttributes {
    id: number;
    uri?: string;
    groupId?: string;
    status?: string;
    tryCount?: number;
    createdDate: Date;
    startDate?: Date;
    completedDate?: Date;
    bodyType?: string;
    formData?: string;
    pageResponse?: string;
    domain?: string;
}

class RequestQ {
    id: number;
    uri?: string;
    groupId?: string;
    status?: string;
    tryCount?: number;
    createdDate: Date;
    startDate?: Date;
    completedDate?: Date;
    bodyType?: string;
    formData?: string;
    pageResponse?: string;
    domain?: string;

    constructor(requestQ: requestQAttributes) {
        this.id = requestQ.id;
        this.uri = requestQ.uri;
        this.groupId = requestQ.groupId;
        this.status = requestQ.status;
        this.tryCount = requestQ.tryCount;
        this.startDate = requestQ.startDate;
        this.completedDate = requestQ.completedDate;
        this.bodyType = requestQ.bodyType;
        this.formData = requestQ.formData;
        this.pageResponse = requestQ.pageResponse;
        this.domain = requestQ.domain;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/W44l1W) work for you?  If not, please demonstrate a use case where something goes wrong.

Comment: There's also [this technique](https://tsplay.dev/NalqBw), which might compose better.  Let me know which one of these, if any, you'd like to see as an answer.